# Shouldn't that be $g(x)$ instead of $f(g)$ in my book?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I'm a beginner at calculus and limits. The following was written in my textbook which confused me a little:

> If $\lim_ {x \to a} f(x)=l$ and $\lim_ {x \to a} g(x)=m$, then
> (a) $\lim_ {x \to a} \{f(x) \pm g(x)\}=\lim_ {x \to a} f(x) \pm \lim_{x \to a} \color\red {f(g)}=l \pm m$
> (b) $\lim_ {x \to a} f(x)g(x)=\lim_ {x \to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_ {x \to a} \color\red {f(g)}=lm$

I'm confused of the $f(g)$ (text in red) sign. Shouldn't that be $g(x)$ instead of that? If not, what does $f(g)$ mean? Does that mean $f(g(x))$?

Comment: It should be $g(x)$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was almost sure about it. By the way, is there any sign named $f(g)$? @Asher2211

Comment: I'm assuming that $f(g)$ would refer to the composite function $f(g(x))$ when suppressing the $x$ value, similar to how one might write $f$ instead of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, let me summarize as a definitive answer that is for sure a typo, since these are little lemmas about the algebra of limits.

If this kind of things happen again, I suggest that you try to give a look at the author's website where it's likely you'll find an errata page (beyond asking your doubts here, obviously).